# Converting pdf pages to png images with pdftoppm changes some fonts

Tags: fonts, pdf, conversion

I need to creates PNG files from a PDF one. Each PGN file corresponds to a slide in the PDF. To do so, I am using pdftoppm (version 0.71.0). All works well, except for some font switches. Look the example bellow. The text is in Portuguese.

[PDF slide[image: 1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/885P4.png)

[PNG image[image: 2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rj5wN.png)

That makes imagine that pdftoppm interprets the pdffile, renderezing internally  a image without finding the correct font. Anyway, how to handle this problem?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[aspectratio:196]{beamer}
% - - Unpacking - -%
% Structurals
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
% Paragraphs
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{xcolor}
% - - Meta Reasons for this Document - -%
\title{Lore Ipsum Im Manibus}
\institute{Hell's Gate}
%
%
\AtEndDocument{%
    \thatisallfolks
  \immediate\closeout13
}
% - - Packages Configuration - -%
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{spruce}
\useinnertheme{circles}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=green!49!black!68}
\titlegraphic{%
  \vspace{1.3cm}
  {\leavevmode\hfil}
  \begin{picture}(0,0)
    {\it A PICTURE PLACE}
  \end{picture}
  {\leavevmode\hfil\hfil}
}
% Last Page
\newcommand{\thatisallfolks}{%
    \begingroup
        \font\callig=callig15 at 52pt
        \frame{\vfilneg\hfilneg\hfil\centering \callig FIM}
    \endgroup
}
% for indent easily everywhere in a frame
\def\indenpar{\hskip3ex}

\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}%
\begin{frame}{A maestria de Newton}

    \begin{block}{Uma defini\c c\~ao simples e bem pensada}
\indenpar Et dorime et latire quae sumus in caelum et Terrae. Quam nunca sunt aemos herideti hic hoc humus unus solis qua spatiro et bulaea. Pugnatur romanus quam et in Lastima. Necamini et inhumenix ad solum et pro laboris ultra facimus sed non amor.
    \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

now, on a console (linux)

> pdflatex  outputpdflatex.tex
> pdftoppm  outputpdflatex.pdf pdf -png

And you will get probably a png picture using a different font.

Comment: One most common application for PDF to PNG convertion is ImageMagick.

Comment: @vipa Which uses GhostScript.

Comment: Without a MWE, we can’t test this for ourselves. One possible explanation is font hinting.

Comment: A minimal structure of my document was added to the topic/post. I have tested. It reproduces the related effect.